# Manejar RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual quiero capturar como un `try-except` la división por cero, sin embargo, me sale el error mencionado en el título y me imprime `inf`. ¿Cómo debo manejar este Warning?

```
import numpy as np

p1 = np.array((1,2))
p2 = p1

def f(p1,p2):
    try:
        x = 1/(np.linalg.norm(p1-p2)**2)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        x = 0
    return x

f(p1,p2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes capturar el warning con `try-except` porque no es una excepción (implica la terminación del proceso de forma inmediata), es solo una advertencia (lo cual no significa que deba ser ignorada sistemáticamente).

Puedes usar el módulo `warnings` de Python para capturar y filtrar warnings de forma genérica, o hacer que NumPy eleve todos los warnings o solo éste a categoría de excepción con [`numpy.seterr()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html#numpy.seterr), pero esto tiene consecuencias globales y personalmente no me gusta (aunque puedes revertirlo después manualmente).

En mi opinión lo más simple, dado que tienes perfectamente delimitado que es lo que quieres manejar, es usar [`numpy.errstate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html) (gestor de contexto) junto a `with`. En la documentación tienes un ejemplo con `invalid` en vez de con `division`, pero la idea es la misma:

```
import numpy as np

p1 = np.array((1,2))
p2 = p1

def f(p1,p2):
    with np.errstate(divide='raise'):
        try:
            x = 1/(np.linalg.norm(p1-p2)**2)
        except FloatingPointError:
            x = 0
        return x

f(p1,p2))
```

El anterior warning pasa a constituir una excepción solamente dentro del bloque `with`, una vez fuera del mimsmo todo vuelve a su estado normal, si fuera del bloque `with` se vuelve a dar la misma situación se lanza el warning, no una excepción, por lo que no se modifica el manejo global de warning y excepciones en todo el módulo.

Answer (score 0):

Según al documentación de [numpy.divide()](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html)

> Division by zero always yields zero in integer arithmetic, and does not raise an  exception or a warning:

Vale decir, la división por 0 entre arrays de numpy no arroja una excepción. Pero es posible modificar este comportamiento, mediante [`numpy.seterr()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html):

```
import numpy as np

p1 = np.array((1,2))
p2 = p1

def f(p1,p2):

    old_settings = np.seterr(divide='raise')
    try:
        x = 1/(np.linalg.norm(p1-p2)**2)
    except FloatingPointError:
        x = 0
    np.seterr(**old_settings)
    return x
```